# 'gem' fails when valid version is specified

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm unable to install the ruby gem 'sys-proctable' when I specify a particular version:

```
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install sys-proctable -v 0.9.6 --verbose --explain
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sys-proctable
200 OK
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sys-proctable' (= 0.9.6) in any repository
GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: sys-proctable
```

However, if I don't specify a version explicitly, it works, **using the exact same version I tried to use before**:

```
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install sys-proctable --verbose --explain
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sys-proctable
200 OK
Gems to install:
  sys-proctable-0.9.6
```

Specifying the version using the colon syntax (`sys-proctable:0.9.6`) doesn't make any difference, or specifying platform with `--platform universal-linux`.

When I download https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=sys-proctable directly, version 0.9.6 for linux is in fact present.

What could be wrong? The version of `gem` is 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with the version of rubygems that Chef bundles: https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3033

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
gem install sys-proctable '0.9.6'
```